# Nested ng-table rendering issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I've got an issue connected with ng-table. I'm using Angular v.1.3.8 and ng-table v.0.8.3. I want to create one paginated ng-table where I could have nested ng-table in each row. But I've got a problem with headers that are not rendering properly. Outer table has all of the headers (including nested table's headers).

Here is my sample code:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngTable"]);
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "ngTableParams", function MyController($scope, ngTableParams) {
    // Prepare data
    $scope.data = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var list = [];
      for (var t = 1; t <= 10; t++) {
        list.push({id: t, name: 'Nested '+i*t})
      }
      $scope.data.push({id: i, name: 'Test '+i, nested: list});
    }
    
    // Prepare tables
    $scope.nestedTableParams = new ngTableParams({}, {});
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
      page: 1,
      count: 10
    }, {
      total: $scope.data.length,
      getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve($scope.data);
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="ng-table@0.8.3" data-semver="0.8.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ng-table@0.8.3" data-semver="0.8.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Nested ng-table example</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped" ng-table="tableParams">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td data-title="'ID'">{{row.id}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Name'">{{row.name}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Nested'">
            <table class="table table-striped" ng-table="nestedTableParams">
              <tr ng-repeat="elem in row.nested">
                <td data-title="'Nested ID'">{{elem.id}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Nested Name'">{{elem.name}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I've prepared Plnkr as an example of my issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/FjpdxLqliUN1B03ONvo4?p=preview

Also, I've got another question. Why do I have to iterate over row.nested instead of $data (as in outer table) in line 23?